# How to get the same to specify the number of bins Pandas.cut return specific

Tags: python, pandas

If I wanted to convert a continuous variable to a categorical variable in Pandas I would use pd.cut(). If I wanted to return a specific number of bins from the function, how do I do this? 
The code below shows the pd.cut function in action. The thing is, the number of bins returned doesn't match the number of labels. Is there a way to fix this?

```
labels = ['never', 'sometimes', 'often']
series, bins = pd.cut(df["column"], bins=3, retbins=True, labels=labels)
```

I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Add sample data, your current output with code, and expected output please.

Comment: Hmm, maybe need [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html).

Comment: What difference will qcut make @jezrael?